# Unit testing with netty 4

Tags: unit-testing, netty

Our application is built using Netty 4 websockets. We are trying to write unit testcases. In that process we want to mock ChannelHandlerContext, Channel, PipeLine etc. Can someone suggest how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: PowerMock, or EasyMock...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to unit test netty handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19312306/how-to-unit-test-netty-handler)

Answer (score 3):

I think you should just use EmbeddedChannel for testing your ChannelHandlers. See other tests included in Netty how todo this.