# How to unit test netty handler

Tags: unit-testing, netty

I implement a handler which extends SimpleChannelHandler, and overrides some methods such as channelConnected, messageReceived. However, I am wondering how to unit test it？

I searched about "netty unit test" and found [one article](http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/netty-users/2009-August/001052.html) which said considering CodecEmbedder, but I am still not sure how to begin. Do you have any example or advice on how to unit test Netty code?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 19):

In Netty, there are different ways to test your networking stack.

### Testing ChannelHandlers

You can use Netty's `EmbeddedChannel` to mock a netty connection for testing, an example of this would be:

```java
@Test
public void nettyTest() {
    EmbeddedChannel channel = new EmbeddedChannel(new StringDecoder(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    channel.writeInbound(Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(new byte[]{(byte)0xE2,(byte)0x98,(byte)0xA2}));
    String myObject = channel.readInbound();
    // Perform checks on your object
    assertEquals("☢", myObject);
}
```

This test above tests for StringDecoder ability to decode unicode correct ([example from this bug posted by me](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/4690))

You can also test the encoder direction using `EmbeddedChannel`, for this you should use `writeOutBound` and `readInbound`.

**More Examples:**

[*DelimiterBasedFrameDecoderTest.java*](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/43ebbc3fa065155fa67732b0cbd7c12843b0f3f7/codec/src/test/java/io/netty/handler/codec/DelimiterBasedFrameDecoderTest.java):

```java
@Test
public void testIncompleteLinesStrippedDelimiters() {
    EmbeddedChannel ch = new EmbeddedChannel(new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(8192, true,
            Delimiters.lineDelimiter()));
    ch.writeInbound(Unpooled.copiedBuffer("Test", Charset.defaultCharset()));
    assertNull(ch.readInbound());
    ch.writeInbound(Unpooled.copiedBuffer("Line\r\ng\r\n", Charset.defaultCharset()));
    assertEquals("TestLine", releaseLater((ByteBuf) ch.readInbound()).toString(Charset.defaultCharset()));
    assertEquals("g", releaseLater((ByteBuf) ch.readInbound()).toString(Charset.defaultCharset()));
    assertNull(ch.readInbound());
    ch.finish();
}
```

*[More examples on github.](https://github.com/netty/netty/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=EmbeddedChannel)*

### ByteBuf

To test if you use your `bytebuf`s, you can set a JVM parameter that checks for leaked ByteBuf, for this, you should add `-Dio.netty.leakDetectionLevel=PARANOID` to the startup parameters, or call the method `ResourceLeakDetector.setLevel(PARANOID)`.

Comment: It took me a little time until I understood it, but I made it work. I simply replaced the parameter in the constructor for EmbeddedChannel with my ChannelHandler.
Did you find a way no to repeat so much code? I mean...
channel = new EmbeddedChannel(new MessageHandler1());
channel = new EmbeddedChannel(new MessageHandler2());
etc...

Comment: Thanks! I have been using Netty a while and never knew how to test me handler logic other then settings up a server! This will save me so much time!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @Ferrybig The tests you showed and some of the examples on the github link make sense in that you are testing a specific network protocol or a certain rule.  What about handlers that do some other business logic action.  Like if I have an AuthHandler that has an authService that validates the user.  I have UT for authService, but essentially channelReadComplete just calls authService.validate(user).  Are those scenarios that are testable still?

Comment: How do you suggest we pass or fail a test when using `ResourceLeakDetector.setLevel(PARANOID)`?

Comment: @Ferrybig Helped me big time. Thanks!!