# Can Netty automatically handle queueing of requests?

Tags: netty, apache-plc4x

In the Apache PLC4X project (https://plc4x.apache.org) we are implementing drivers for industrial PLCs using Netty. Here usually a variety of protocols are layered. Some times one layer requires us to split up one message into multiple messages of the underlying layer. Now we are facing one big problem: One protocol negotiates a maximum number of unconfirmed messages per connection. So we can't send more messages to that than this maximum or the receiver will simply send an error response.

Now we would need to not add things to "out" in the encode method, but to add them to some sort of queue and have some Netty mechanism take care of draining that queue ... is there such a mechanism in Netty? If not, what would be the best way to implement this?

Would also be cool if someone with good Netty insight could join our project mailing list (dev@plc4x.apache.org) as we're also working on some really cool additions for Netty (Raw Socket transport on Ethernet Frame and one on IP packet base) ... I bet both projects could benefit greatly from each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While Netty does not provide such a handler out of the box, but because of the internal design, it is really easy to make such max concurrent pending requests out of the box.

Making such handler can be done using the [`PendingWriteQueue`](https://netty.io/4.0/api/index.html?io/netty/channel/PendingWriteQueue.html) class from the Netty framework in combination with a generic handler:

```java
import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerAdapter;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelPromise;
import io.netty.channel.PendingWriteQueue;

public class MaxPendingRequestHandler extends ChannelHandlerAdapter {

    private PendingWriteQueue queue;
    private int freeSlots;

    public MaxPendingRequestHandler(int maxRequests) {
        this.freeSlots = maxRequests;
    }

    private synchronized void trySendMessages(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        if(this.freeSlots > 0) {
            while(this.freeSlots > 0) {
                if(this.queue.removeAndWrite() == null) {
                    ctx.flush();
                    return;
                }
                this.freeSlots--;
            }
            ctx.flush();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void channelRegistered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        this.queue = new PendingWriteQueue(ctx);
    }

    @Override
    public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        // Send everything so we get a proper failurefor those pending writes
        this.queue.removeAndWriteAll();
        super.channelInactive(ctx);
    }

    @Override
    public void channelUnregistered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        this.queue.removeAndWriteAll();
        super.channelUnregistered(ctx);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg, ChannelPromise promise) throws Exception {
        this.queue.add(msg, promise);
        trySendMessages(ctx);
    }

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
        synchronized(this) {
            this.freeSlots++;
            trySendMessages(ctx);
        }
        super.channelRead(ctx, msg);
    }

}
```

This handler works on the fact that it saves every new message in a queue, and it checks the free slots on the wire on every write/read.

Notice that handler should be placed in the pipeline after the packet decoders/encoders, else problems happen with counting incoming packets as potential multiple packets, example:

```java
pipeline.addLast(new PacketCodex()); // A codex exists of an encoder and decoder, you can also ass them seperately
// pipeline.addLast(new TrafficShapingHandler()) // Optional, depending on your required protocols
// pipeline.addLast(new IdleStateHandler())      // Optional, depending on your required protocols
pipeline.addLast(new MaxPendingRequestHandler())
pipeline.addLast(new Businesshandler())
```

Of course, you also want to verify that our handler works, this can be done using a Unit test containing a [`EmbeddedChannel`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34790002/1542723) & JUnit:

```java
public class MaxPendingRequestHandlerTest {

    @Test
    public void testMaxPending() {
        EmbeddedChannel channel = new EmbeddedChannel(new MaxPendingRequestHandler(3));

        // channel.writeOutbound("1", "2", "3"); // This doesn't work as it expects operations to complete directly

        channel.write("1");
        channel.write("2");
        channel.write("3");
        channel.write("4");
        channel.write("5");
        channel.write("6");

        Assert.assertEquals(channel.readOutbound(), "1");
        Assert.assertEquals(channel.readOutbound(), "2");
        Assert.assertEquals(channel.readOutbound(), "3");
        Assert.assertEquals(channel.readOutbound(), (Object)null);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMaxPendingWhenAResponseHasReceived() {
        EmbeddedChannel channel = new EmbeddedChannel(new MaxPendingRequestHandler(3));

        // channel.writeOutbound("1", "2", "3"); // This doesn't work as it expects operations to complete directly

        channel.write("1");
        channel.write("2");
        channel.write("3");
        channel.write("4");
        channel.write("5");
        channel.write("6");

        channel.writeInbound("RE: 1");

        Assert.assertEquals(channel.readOutbound(), "1");
        Assert.assertEquals(channel.readOutbound(), "2");
        Assert.assertEquals(channel.readOutbound(), "3");
        Assert.assertEquals(channel.readOutbound(), "4");
        Assert.assertEquals(channel.readOutbound(), (Object)null);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMaxPendingWhenAllResponseHasReceived() {
        EmbeddedChannel channel = new EmbeddedChannel(new MaxPendingRequestHandler(3));

        // channel.writeOutbound("1", "2", "3"); // This doesn't work as it expects operations to complete directly

        channel.write("1");
        channel.write("2");
        channel.write("3");
        channel.write("4");
        channel.write("5");
        channel.write("6");

        channel.writeInbound("RE: 1");
        channel.writeInbound("RE: 2");
        channel.writeInbound("RE: 3");
        channel.writeInbound("RE: 4");
        channel.writeInbound("RE: 5");
        channel.writeInbound("RE: 6");

        Assert.assertEquals(channel.readOutbound(), "1");
        Assert.assertEquals(channel.readOutbound(), "2");
        Assert.assertEquals(channel.readOutbound(), "3");
        Assert.assertEquals(channel.readOutbound(), "4");
        Assert.assertEquals(channel.readOutbound(), "5");
        Assert.assertEquals(channel.readOutbound(), "6");
        Assert.assertEquals(channel.readOutbound(), (Object)null);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMaxPendingWhenAllResponseHasReceivedAndNewMessagesAreSend() {
        EmbeddedChannel channel = new EmbeddedChannel(new MaxPendingRequestHandler(3));

        // channel.writeOutbound("1", "2", "3"); // This doesn't work as it expects operations to complete directly

        channel.write("1");
        channel.write("2");
        channel.write("3");
        channel.write("4");
        channel.write("5");
        channel.write("6");

        channel.writeInbound("RE: 1");
        channel.writeInbound("RE: 2");
        channel.writeInbound("RE: 3");
        channel.writeInbound("RE: 4");
        channel.writeInbound("RE: 5");
        channel.writeInbound("RE: 6");

        channel.write("7");
        channel.write("8");
        channel.write("9");
        channel.write("10");

        Assert.assertEquals(channel.readOutbound(), "1");
        Assert.assertEquals(channel.readOutbound(), "2");
        Assert.assertEquals(channel.readOutbound(), "3");
        Assert.assertEquals(channel.readOutbound(), "4");
        Assert.assertEquals(channel.readOutbound(), "5");
        Assert.assertEquals(channel.readOutbound(), "6");
        Assert.assertEquals(channel.readOutbound(), "7");
        Assert.assertEquals(channel.readOutbound(), "8");
        Assert.assertEquals(channel.readOutbound(), "9");
        Assert.assertEquals(channel.readOutbound(), (Object)null);
    }

}
```

Comment: Wow ... thanks for this extremely helpful response ... I did too stumble over the PendingWriteQueue and started playing around with it ... You suggest the above logic to be in the last layer ... however the concept of limiting the number of requests is part of an intermediate layer ... I did see some code examples that also implemented/overrided some flush logic but your: channelInactive method solution would also handle sending out things as other requests got acked, correct?

Comment: And another but formally important question ... am I allowed to use the code you posted in an Apache licensed project (Apache PLC4X)?

Comment: I don't have any problems with re-licensing, as I think it's basically trivial code, it only contains really 18 lines of real logic. Feel free to licence under your projects licence

Comment: Ok ... so I implemented this and it seems to generally do the trick ... at least as long as all messages of one request go out in one batch. But if I have to interrupt sending requests as the limit is reached, I have to wait for responses to come back in. If a response comes in and I can therefore remove one item from my "sent but unconfirmed messages" list, I call trySendingMessages again, but then I get the following error: 11:19:35.698 [...] WARN  i.n.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer - Failed to mark a promise as success because it has succeeded already: DefaultChannelPromise@751f63b(success)

Comment: Is there a way you can capture that behaviour in a unit test? As far as I know, the handler that I made only uses `removeAndWrite...`, so it shouldn't try to write the same message multiple times, unless the upstream calls writes multiple ties with the same promise, what is against the specification

Comment: So I updated my code again to simply exit the loop after sending one element. All seems to be ok if I send all parts in one go. If I continue sending pending messages later on, it seems the original promise in the individual requests is closed. How can I prevent the not-sent promisses from being closed?

Comment: Ok and some more info ... I guess the problem could be related to my handler consuming one message and writing multiple messages to the queue. Right now I'm passing in the original promise, but with this, this promise gets finished as soon as the first elements get sent. It sort of feels like I have to introduce some sort of intermediate proxy promise, that gets accepted if all sub-message promisses get accepted ... correct?

Comment: Ok ... I'm finished ... I ended up with creating one new Promise for every sub-request and then using a PromiseCombiner to handle the original promise. See here: https://github.com/apache/incubator-plc4x/blob/master/plc4j/protocols/s7/src/main/java/org/apache/plc4x/java/s7/netty/S7Protocol.java to see the code