# Spring Boot how to test Netty Handler?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, netty

I have a Netty TCP Server with Spring Boot `2.3.1`.

I have been looking for many resources for testing handlers for Netty, like

- [Testing Netty with EmbeddedChannel](https://www.baeldung.com/testing-netty-embedded-channel)
- [How to unit test netty handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19312306/how-to-unit-test-netty-handler/34790002)

However, it didn't work for me.

For EmbeddedChannel I have following error - `Your remote address is embedded.`

Here is code:

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ProcessingHandlerTest_Embedded {

    @Mock
    private PermissionService permissionService;
    private EmbeddedChannel embeddedChannel;
    private final Gson gson = new Gson();

    private ProcessingHandler processingHandler;


    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        processingHandler = new ProcessingHandler(permissionService);
        embeddedChannel = new EmbeddedChannel(processingHandler);
    }

    @Test
    public void testHeartbeatMessage() {
        // given
        HeartbeatRequest heartbeatMessage = HeartbeatRequest.builder()
                .messageID("heartbeat")
                .build();

        HeartbeatResponse response = HeartbeatResponse.builder()
                .responseCode("ok")
                .build();
        String request = gson.toJson(heartbeatMessage).concat("\r\n");
        String expected = gson.toJson(response).concat("\r\n");

        // when
        embeddedChannel.writeInbound(request);

        // then
        Queue<Object> outboundMessages = embeddedChannel.outboundMessages();
        assertEquals(expected, outboundMessages.poll());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
22:21:29.062 [main] INFO handler.ProcessingHandler - CLIENT_IP: embedded
22:21:29.062 [main] INFO handler.ProcessingHandler - CLIENT_REQUEST: {"messageID":"heartbeat"}

22:21:29.067 [main] DEBUG handler.ProcessingHandler - heartbeat request: HeartbeatRequest(messageID=heartbeat)

org.junit.ComparisonFailure: 
<Click to see difference>
```

[image]

I tried something with a remote address:

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ProcessingHandlerTest {

    @Mock
    private PermissionService permissionService;
    private final Gson gson = new Gson();

    private ProcessingHandler processingHandler;

    @Mock
    private ChannelHandlerContext channelHandlerContext;

    @Mock
    private Channel channel;

    @Mock
    private SocketAddress remoteAddress;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        processingHandler = new ProcessingHandler(permissionService);
        when(channelHandlerContext.channel()).thenReturn(channel);
        when(channelHandlerContext.channel().remoteAddress()).thenReturn(remoteAddress);
    }

    @Test
    public void testHeartbeatMessage() {
        // given
        HeartbeatRequest heartbeatMessage = HeartbeatRequest.builder()
                .messageID("heartbeat")
                .build();

        HeartbeatResponse response = HeartbeatResponse.builder()
                .responseCode("ok")
                .build();
        String request = gson.toJson(heartbeatMessage).concat("\r\n");
        String expected = gson.toJson(response).concat("\r\n");

        // when
        processingHandler.channelRead(channelHandlerContext, request);

        // then
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
22:26:06.119 [main] INFO handler.ProcessingHandler - CLIENT_IP: null
22:26:06.124 [main] INFO handler.ProcessingHandler - CLIENT_REQUEST: {"messageID":"heartbeat"}

22:26:06.127 [main] DEBUG handler.ProcessingHandler - heartbeat request: HeartbeatRequest(messageID=heartbeat)
```

However, I don't know how to do exact testing for such a case.

Here is a snippet from configuration:

```
@Bean
@SneakyThrows
public InetSocketAddress tcpSocketAddress() {
    // for now, hostname is: localhost/127.0.0.1:9090
    return new InetSocketAddress("localhost", nettyProperties.getTcpPort());

    // for real client devices: A05264/172.28.1.162:9090
    // return new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), nettyProperties.getTcpPort());
}

@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class QrReaderChannelInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {

    private final StringEncoder stringEncoder = new StringEncoder();
    private final StringDecoder stringDecoder = new StringDecoder();

    private final QrReaderProcessingHandler readerServerHandler;
    private final NettyProperties nettyProperties;

    @Override
    protected void initChannel(SocketChannel socketChannel) {
        ChannelPipeline pipeline = socketChannel.pipeline();

        // Add the text line codec combination first
        pipeline.addLast(new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(1024 * 1024, Delimiters.lineDelimiter()));

        pipeline.addLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(nettyProperties.getClientTimeout()));
        pipeline.addLast(stringDecoder);
        pipeline.addLast(stringEncoder);
        pipeline.addLast(readerServerHandler);
    }
}
```

The handler is a typical implementation of `ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter` with overriding main methods.

***How to test Handler with Spring Boot?***

Comment: Could you post the stack trace for your error?

Comment: @CamW done for both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `Your remote address is embedded.` isn't so much an error as it is, unexpected output which you're receiving.

There isn't anything special about how netty tests should be written for Spring Boot. As an example, here is a minimal test for a handler which always outputs "ok":

```
import io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf;
import io.netty.buffer.Unpooled;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelFutureListener;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter;
import io.netty.channel.embedded.EmbeddedChannel;
import io.netty.util.CharsetUtil;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

@SpringBootTest
class DemoApplicationTests {

    @Test
    void testRoundTrip() {
        // given
        String request = "heartbeat";

        // when
        EmbeddedChannel embeddedChannel = new EmbeddedChannel(new OkResponder());
        embeddedChannel.writeInbound(request);

        // then
        ByteBuf outboundMessage = embeddedChannel.readOutbound();
        //(ByteBuf)embeddedChannel.outboundMessages().poll(), as you've used, works in the above line too.
        assertEquals("ok", outboundMessage.toString(CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
    }

    static class OkResponder extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {
        @Override
        public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
            ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer("ok", CharsetUtil.UTF_8))
                    .addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
        }
    }
}
```

It looks to me that your `ProcessingHandler` is calling `ctx.channel().remoteAddress()` at some point which will return "embedded" for an EmbeddedChannel and that is causing the output that you're seeing.

Comment: you are right at handler I have to call  `ctx.channel().remoteAddress().toString()` - I need to know the IP address of the client to identify him. It is very needed for business logic. Is it possible to write a test with `remoteAddress` identification, too?

Comment: I suggest you trace the code from that point to understand why you're receiving the message that you are. Without seeing the handler there's nothing more I can add. This answer answers the originally stated question, asking how to test a netty handler in spring boot. If you need more assistance, create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and ask a question based on that.

Comment: did it [Netty how to test Handler which uses Remote Address of a client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63209649/netty-how-to-test-handler-which-uses-remote-address-of-a-client)